# Open application on custom desktop in xmonad

Tags: emacs, desktop, window, xmonad, evince

Suppose I call `shell-command` from `emacs` for example `(shell-command "evince")`. Is it possible to move the application (in the present example `evince`) started this way automatically to desktop `5` in `xmonad`.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of *do one thing and do it well*, [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) was created for these kinds of issues *with any [standards-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMH) WM* ([such as properly-configured XMonad](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-EwmhDesktops.html), also see [the FAQ](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions)).

Some configuration along the lines (adopted from [this tutorial](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/25/how-to-set-default-workspace-size-and-window-effects-in-gnome/), I do not know if this way of matching Evince actually works, maybe some other way (see the docs) is needed) of

```
(if
  (is (application_name) "Evince")
    (begin
    (set_workspace 5)
    (maximize)
  )
)
```

should do the job.  Note that Devil's Pie [has been mentioned quite often around here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=devil+pie), there might be more useful information just a click away.

Answer (score 1):

A pure xmonad configuration is possible for that. In your `.xmonad/xmonad.hs` you need to setup a manageHook for that. I included more than one "rule" on purpose.

```
theManageHook = composeAll [
    -- send applications to the right workspace
    className =? "Evince" --> doShift "5",
    className =? "Pidgin" --> doShift "4"
    --- more settings ...
]

main = do
    xmonad $ gnomeConfig { 
        manageHook = theManageHook <+> manageHook gnomeConfig
    }
```

You can see the className of given Window with `xprop` and clicking on the desired window. className refers to the second entry in the xprop-output. If you only want some xproperties, `xprop` accepts them as arguments:

```
~ $ xprop WM_CLASS WM_NAME
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "evince", "Evince"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Document Viewer"
```

More on that can be found in the [Xmonad FAQ](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#I_need_to_find_the_class_title_or_some_other_X_property_of_my_program).

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I only want to move the application to a specific desktop if I start it from my emacs script.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the initial WM_CLASS is different. Can you try to match the resource instead of the className? What do the emacs say about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `xdotool` to change the window's class then you can move it to Desktop `5` with `XMonad` or Devil's pie.

```
#!/bin/sh
$1 &
NEW_WINDOW_PID=$!

WINDOW_EXISTENCE=$(xdotool search --pid ${NEW_WINDOW_PID} 2> /dev/null) #is empty if the window hasn't finished opening.
COUNTER=0
while [[ -z $WINDOW_EXISTENCE && $COUNTER < 6 ]] #waits for the window to open
do
    WINDOW_EXISTENCE=$(xdotool search --pid ${NEW_WINDOW_PID} 2> /dev/null)
    sleep 1
    (( COUNTER++ ))
done

if [ $COUNTER != "6" ]; then
    NEW_WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid ${NEW_WINDOW_PID}) #finds the window that was just opened
    xdotool set_window --class yay ${NEW_WINDOW_ID}; #change the class of the window to yay
fi
```

And then write a function in emacs

```
(defun window-in-desktop-5 (cmd)
  "start shell command on desktop 5"
  (interactive "sshell-command: ")
  (shell-command  (concat "/path/to/xdotoolscript " cmd)))
```

Whenever you call a program through the emacs function it will change the class name of the window as long as the PID of the window is the same as the function that called it otherwise the script will time out after six seconds.